# How to fix alert on every candle with startegy

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5

I have a strategy with 2 EMA that is automated by a bot.

When FastMA crossover SlowMA = buy
when FastMA crossunder SlowMA = Sell

When I set my alert on the strategy, it rings on every single candle open rather than on the crossovers, when the strategy should buy or sell. Because of this, my startegy buys and sells or sells and buys instantly therefore canceling out the trade.

My questions is the following: How do i make it that the only alarm that rings is when a crossover/crossunder occurs and an order places itself?

I am running it on Oanda Practice to test it before i run it with real capital

Below is my alert section

```
strategy.entry('Buy', strategy.long, when=goLong())
alert("e=oandapractice a=localhost s=silver b=long q=1 t=market d=5", alert.freq_all)
alert("e=oandapractice a=localhost s=silver q=1 t=market c=position", alert.freq_all)

strategy.entry('Sell', strategy.short, when=goShort())
alert("e=oandapractice a=localhost s=silver b=short q=1 t=market d=5", alert.freq_all)
alert("e=oandapractice a=localhost s=silver q=1 t=market c=position", alert.freq_all)
```

Comment: `strategy.entry` has a parameter `when=` where you should add the variable that holds the conditional which signals the trade (simpler: when that variable is TRUE `strategy.entry` will execute, otherwise it won't ). Some people like to enclose the entire `strategy.entry` in an IF statement but Pine doesn't handle IFs and FOR loops well (this is a longer story), so the best practice is to set a variable or execute a line of code **every time** which might not happen if you put it behind an IF statement and its conditional is FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an if condition to trigger your alerts.

Something like:

```
is_new_long_position = strategy.position_size[1] == 0 and strategy.position_size > 0

if (is_new_long_position)
    alert("e=oandapractice a=localhost s=silver b=long q=1 t=market d=5", alert.freq_all)
    alert("e=oandapractice a=localhost s=silver q=1 t=market c=position", alert.freq_all)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give this a try and will let you know. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hey man, I had to modify the If statement to go with my goLong goShort but otherwise the If statement made it work perfectly. Thank you so much, this is much appreciated!!